# Syntax Error 'break outside loop'

Tags: python, function

Essentially, I'm trying to create a main function that can take input, and use that list of input to calculate the median, mode, and mean by using another function. I'm a novice coder (taking my first class) so any help that can point me in the right direction while still helping me learn will be greatly appreciated.

```
def median(alist):

    srtd = sorted(alist)
    mid = len(alist) // 2 

    if len(alist) % 2 == 0:
        return (srtd[mid -1] + srtd[mid]) / 2.0
    else: 
        return (srtd[mid]) 

def main(): 

    yourlist = []
    addons = list(float(input("Enter your list of number to be calculated(stop to stop): ")))


    if addons != "stop": 
        data.append(yourlist)

    elif addons == "stop":      
        break
    else:
        print("Bad input, try again: ")
        continue

    medresult = median(yourlist)
    return medresult


print(medresult)
```

Comment: What do you think `break` and `continue` will do? Are they different? Do you know about `pass`?

Comment: Why are you calling `break` in `main()` definition? `break` is used to break out of loops. It has no meaning outside a loop

Comment: `medresult` is only defined within your function `main`. The `print` statement won't know what `medresult` refers to.

Comment: You should return in a function, also `list(1.0)` makes no sense nor does `list(any_number)`, read a tutorial  http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/getting-started.html, you are not even close to having a working program

Comment: Peter, my thought was break would exit the loop once the user enters stop to complete their input so the script could move on and calculate the median. I haven't learned pass yet.

Comment: Apparently there is no loop in the main function!

Comment: And why have an else block? Your input will either be stop or not, therfore you can never get to the else.

Comment: Did you intend to write a loop? There's no loop here.

Comment: Okay, so I understand what you guys are saying. I added the "While True:" and that must've fixed it because I got a different error to work with now. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal preference, but I would change your if statements to

```
if 'stop' not in addons:
    data.append(yourlist)
```

and the elif to

```
elif not all(isinstance(number, float) for number in addons):
    print("Bad input, try again")
```

This checks each inputted number in the addons list to see if it is a float. If not all are floats, then print the try again message

Answer (score 1):

`break` and `continue` are to only be used in a loop such as `for` or `while`

So your main () should have a while loop in it.

```
def main(): 

  yourlist = []
  while True:      
    addons = input("Enter your list of number to be calculated(stop to stop): ")


    if addons != "stop": 
      data.append(yourlist)

    elif addons == "stop":      
      break
    else:
      # This block will never run because an input can either equal or not equal "stop"
      print("Bad input, try again: ")
      continue
```